# Relacionamento entre classes composite key → erro: not mapped to a single property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Eu tenho uma classe CVariacaoTO que possui uma chave composta (FK_T, FK_F, FK_F_VARIACAO). Dois desses campos de chave primária (FK_F, FK_F_VARIACAO) são também chave estrangeira para a tabela FVariacaoTO, em um relacionamento ManyToOne

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_F", referencedColumnName = "FK_F", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_F_V", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
@NotNull
private FVariacaoTO fVariacaoTO;
```

A classe FVariacaoTO possui duas chaves primárias, que estão sendo referenciadas, dentro de uma classe FVariacaoPK.

**Estou obtendo o seguinte ERRO**: referencedColumnNames(FK_F, ID) de CVariacaoTO.fVariacaoTO not mapped to a single property

O que normalmente causa este erro?
*Como posso resolver este relacionamento?*

---

EDIT: Informações adicionais.

Na classe FVariacaoTO, a chave está como @EmbeddedId, da seguinte maneira:

```
@EmbeddedId @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "fkF", column = @Column(name = "fkF", nullable = false)), @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)) }) @NotNull private FVariacaoPK fVariacaoPK;
```

E na clase FVariacaoPK, que possui essa ID indicada no @EmbeddedId, está assim:

```
@Column(name = "FK_F", nullable = false) private int fkF;

@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false) private int id;
```

Comment: Sua pergunta esta complicada para entender, tenta colocar o erro que esta ocorrendo e sua causa, junto com as classes com formatação de código. Assim fica difícil te ajudar. Mas este erro ocorre quando você esta setando o 'id' de um mapeamento mais de uma vez. Quando for necessário subscrever um id é necessário utilizar  @AttributeOverride(name="id",column=@Column(name="NOVA_ID"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ainda não pude rodar a aplicação porque existem outros problemas a serem resolvidos, mas fazendo da seguinte maneira o compilador deixou de reclamar sobre esta questão:

`@JoinColumn(name = "FK_F", referencedColumnName = "fkF", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_F_V", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)`

Indiquei no referencedColumnName o nome do campo na entidade referenciada, FVariacaoTO, e não no objeto @Embedabble FVariacaoPK, como eu estava fazendo

Apesar de não ter compreendido muito a situação, o problema deixou de ser acusado.